# Reasons for variations in run-time performance of identical code

Tags: c++, linux, performance, performance-testing

when running some benchmarks of my C++ software, I obtained the following picture:  [image]

The plot shows the execution time in nanoseconds of one tick of the software. 
The exact same tick is ran each time (one data point is one tick).

When testing in the simulated environment of valgrind, there is zero difference between each tick, and I don't have syscalls others than what `clock_gettime` may do.

I would like to understand what can cause the two "speeds" in which the tick seems to run. I disabled intel CPU sleep states which greatly helped (before that I had 4 lines like this), and what could be the causes for the outlier points. The scheduler used is linux's FIFO scheduler.

An interesting observation is that the tick times alternate between the two values of 9000 and 6700 ns; here's some data points:

```
9022
6605
9170
6756
9126
6594
9102
6744
9016
6643
8950
6638
9047
6662
```

edit: 
just doing this in a loop in my thread:

```
auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
measure(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count()));
```

is enough for me to see the alternating effect, though between 100 and 150 ns.

Comment: You computer is doing something else and what you are seeing is the effect of the OS-scheduler, background tasks etc..

Comment: 10000 ns is only 10 µs, which is a very short time to be measuring reliably/accurately, particularly in a general-purpose (i.e. not real-time) OS. Also it would help to see some code, e.g. a [mcve].

Comment: The CPU is running to hot and therefore it is throttled.

Comment: Richard Critten: I used the fifo scheduler. Quoting the man page: "A SCHED_FIFO process runs until either it is blocked by an I/O request, it is preempted by a higher priority process, or it calls sched_yield(2).". I set maximal priority to my process and don't call yield or other syscalls in the benchmarked code.

Comment: manni68: I don't think so, it's only at 60-65°C from what I can see. Is there a way to check if throttling happens ?

Comment: Paul R: I agree that this is a pretty short time, but what intrigues me is that the time of each tick really alternates between both values like clockwork; I would expect something more random if it was a question of measurement precision.

Comment: If the program is loaded at different addresses, you can get cache collisions for different parts of your data.

Comment: Bo Persson: the program is only run once and calls the code in a loop ; I measure the duration of each loop. The code in question works on static fixed data.

Comment: At such small granularity there are many possible timing artefacts. If this is an Intel CPU then it may be something like Turbo Boost, which ramps the CPU clock multiplier up and down based on how many cores are active and the core temperature. The two main peaks you are seeing may be one increment of the clock multiplier apart. Disable Turbo Boost in the BIOS to verify.

Comment: Even with `SCHED_FIFO` the OS-scheduler is still running (and other high-priority / kernel tasks) this will dirty the cache etc,

Comment: Paul R: I checked with turbo boost disabled & did everything I could to ensure a fixed CPU frequency and it did not change.